# In Jquery i have replace div with another div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

My First Div as

```
<div class ="amazon">
    <form target="OffAmazonPaymentsPopupWindowA24SYJTTYUTWN2" method="POST" action="https://payments.amazon.com/gp/widgets/widgets" id="OffAmazonPaymentsWidgets0Form" style="display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0; border-width: 0; overflow: hidden;">
     <input type="hidden" value="connect" name="action">
     <input type="hidden" value="https://jsdentallab.com/my-account/checkout/" name="referringURL">
     <input type="hidden" value="A24SYJTTYUTWN2" name="cartOwnerId"><input type="hidden" value="true" name="useAmazonAddressBook">
     <input type="hidden" value="" name="agreementType">
    </form>
 </div> 
  Have an Amazon account?
</div>
   <div id="pay_with_amazon">
      <img src="https://payments.amazon.com/gp/widgets/button?sellerId=A24SYJTTYUTWN2&amp;size=large&amp;color=orange">
   </div>
 </div>
```

That would be replace with **New Blank Div Class**

I have also reffered [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

Can you suggest me

Thank you

Comment: this has to be replaced with which div

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: your one extra div is Closed on 10th line

Comment: My code is $("div.amazon").replaceWith( $( "#payment" ) );

Comment: #payment is my new blank div so amazon div content replace on Payment div

Comment: @Girish My Humberly request do not change the original code people not getting what is exactly my problem

Answer (score 0):

This would do what you ask:

```
$('.amazon').replaceWith($('<div />'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set HTML in div to empty

```
$(".amazon").html("");
```